# Remove "Trash" from Wordpress Pages

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to remove the "trash" link from wordpress **pages** in wp-admin. I have managed to create a function that removes it from posts but cannot seem to find any info on doing the same for pages.

Function for removing trash link from posts:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions', 10, 1 );
function remove_row_actions( $actions )
{
    if( get_post_type() === 'post' )

        unset( $actions['clone'] );
        unset( $actions['trash'] );

    return $actions;
}
?>
```

Comment: edit get_post_type() === 'page'  and try again

Comment: <?php
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions', 10, 1 );
function remove_row_actions( $actions )
{
    if( get_post_type() === 'page' )

        unset( $actions['clone'] );
        unset( $actions['trash'] );

    return $actions;
}
?>

Doesn't seem to work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paste below code into function.php and check in post/page section in admin

```
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions_post', 10, 1 );
function remove_row_actions_post( $actions )
{
if( get_post_type() === 'post' )
{
unset( $actions['clone'] );
unset( $actions['trash'] );
return $actions;
}
}
add_filter( 'page_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions_page', 10, 1 );
function remove_row_actions_page( $actions )
{
if( get_post_type() === 'page' )
{
unset( $actions['clone'] );
unset( $actions['trash'] );
return $actions;
}
}
```

Comment: you mean to remove link of thrash  for edit page/post  screen at admin as well?

Comment: I would like only admins to be able to trash files

Answer (score 1):

Adding this snippet to the functions.php of your wordpress theme will remove the trash functionality

```
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions', 10, 1 );
function remove_row_actions( $actions )
{
    if( get_post_type() === 'post' )
        unset( $actions['trash'] );
     return $actions;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you want to use

```
unset($actions['delete']);
```